# Simple 2-D Projectile motion — Why are these two cases different?

Tags: projectile

I just started studying about projectile motion and have encountered this situation where in

> [Case 1](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BBs6kTdJ_yh04dTZfY6QB0pUy-O9Zb45/view?usp=drivesdk)
> A projectile is launched at an angle of 53° with an initial velocity 'u' from an inclined plane that is angled clockwise at 37° from the ground.

> [Case 2](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BDHk1JcSlXVaih7MYhjn27vNIUWLaR2D/view?usp=drivesdk)
> A projectile is launched at an angle of 16° at the same height as in case 1 with the same initial velocity as in case 1, which means initial velocity = 'u'.

---

Having stated the two questions, I want you to observe and realise that equating the case 1 to case 2 would be sensible because the angle that the projectile is launched at w.r.t. the ground in case 1 is 16° which is equal to the angle at which the projectile is launched w.r.t. the ground in case 2.

---

But my teacher didn't let us use the same formula for both the cases. He derived another formula which was a little confusing although it was derived from the same principles and had a similar base to the general projectile formulae for time of flight, range and maximum height.
Also if you can notice, my teacher divided the gravitational force into components for the case 1 but didn't do so in case 2?
It's really confusing me why we cannot look at case 1 just like case 2?
Why being on an inclined plane makes so much difference? Isn't it just as simple as having an angle from the ground?

Comment: Hi Desai. Welcome to Phys.SE. Linking to private clouds, dropbox, etc, is for various reasons not acceptable on SE, cf. [this](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11400/2451) meta post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although the angle is the same as you say, it was measured with respect to different planes. In the second case, you are applying equations for the horizontal and vetical motions. There the horizontal acceleration is zero while the vertical acceleration is equal to $g$ (downwards). In your first case, you are applying those equations to the motion along the direction parallel to the inclined plane and the direction perpendicular to that plane. As $g$ acts directly downwards, there will be components of acceleration acting along those inclined directions.

> Also if you can notice, my teacher divided the gravitational force into components for the case 1 but didn't do so in case 2?

Actually he did. That's why you get horizontal acceleration zero, becuase vertical acceleration due to gravity has no effect on horizontal direction.